# ¿Cómo cambiar la contraseña de un usuario?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

Estoy intentado que mi pagina web tenga la función de cambiar la contraseña de un usuario pero en todos los tutoriales que he visto utilizan el formulario por defecto sin darle estilo.

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de darle estilo y si en la misma página puedo poner más formularios como cambiar datos del perfil como: *nombre*, *apellidos*, *fecha de nacimiento*, *correo electrónico*.

Espero haberme explicado bien.

No agrego código porque lo que he intentado hasta ahora no me ha funcionado.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacerlo te recomiendo utilizar la vista [`PasswordChangeView`](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.contrib.auth.views/PasswordChangeView/) y para darle estilos al formulario o al HTML como tal, hay que personalizar el form [`PasswordChangeForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.PasswordChangeForm), heredando de el por supuesto:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordChangeForm

class CustomPasswordChangeForm(PasswordChangeForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Le añadimos clases CSS a los inputs
        self.fields['old_password'].widget.attrs.update({'class': '...'})
        self.fields['new_password1'].widget.attrs.update({'class': '...'})
        self.fields['new_password2'].widget.attrs.update({'class': '...'})
```

De esta manera agrega las clases CSS que quieras, dando estilos al formulario HTML generado. Si quieres personalizar mas el formulario por ejemplo poner los `<input>` dentro de ciertos elementos, entonces seria de la siguiente manera:

```
<form  method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="...">
        {{ form.old_password }}
    </div>
    <div class="...">
        ...
        <div class="...">
            {{ form.new_password1 }}
        </div>
    </div>
    <section>
        {{ form.new_password2 }}
    </section>
    <button type="submit">...</button>
</form>
```

Y tu vista debería quedar algo así:

```
class PasswordChangeView(PasswordChangeView):
    template_name = '...' # El tamplate_name por defecto es: 'registration/password_change_form.html'
    form_class = CustomPasswordChangeForm
```

Dicha vista por defecto redirecciona al nombre de patron URL `'password_change_done'`, asi que recuerda sobrescribir el atributo `success_url` si quieres cambiar esto.

Y también si quieres puedes personalizar aun mas la vista [`PasswordChangeView`](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.contrib.auth.views/PasswordChangeView/).

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Muchas gracias, al final lo pude solucionar